# Add second Splash Screen for iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, splash-screen

My app is available for both iPhone and iPad. But in LaunchScreen storyBoard I'm able to enter only one picture(for example for iPhone), this picture looks ridiculous on iPad.

But we also can't create custom class for this screen to display different pictures for different devices, how is it possible to show 2 different pictures in LaunchingScreen in one app for both iPhone and iPad?

Comment: I think your answer is in iOS Human Interface Guidelines :-    https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by [adding an image set](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/chapters/AddingImageSets.html). Then use this image set from you storyboard.

Answer (score 1):

- I think your answer is in iOS Human Interface Guidelines take
  different size of images in image assets.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html